# Use of disgusting

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Recently, while watching some streams of Counter Strike I noticed that the commentators use the word "disgusting" a lot when refering for a nice, good, beautiful play. My question is, can disgusting really mean a good thing? They are really impressed by the play or they are being mean because the play was made by some player they dislike by using this word?

Comment: There is no way to tell if they were being ironic or sarcastic. Please capitalize the pronoun I.

Comment: Without more context... perhaps they thought that a *game* based on terrorism is disgusting, regardless of the supposedly great moves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, "disgusting" can be a good thing. In the context of video games and also in sports, it's common to hear negative words used in a positive way. This is a slang usage. The actual meaning intended is often close to the exact opposite of the word's normal meaning.

[Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=disgusting#3988091) gives us a pretty good definition in this case:

> so impressive or overwhelmingly awesome that it's not "sick," it's disgusting

"Sick" as slang for "good" has been around for a while, and "disgusting" probably evolved out of that as a way to make an even more dramatic comment about how good something is after "sick" became somewhat overused.

So if you hear a commentator talking about a "disgusting play" in CS, you could imagine that the real sentiment is something like:

> That guy (the gamer) is beating the competition so thoroughly that it almost makes me sick to watch. Those poor guys (other team) getting killed so quickly and ruthlessly—it's disgusting.

This is hyperbole, of course, but that's the idea.

You can get this kind of usage with "sick" or different synonyms of it. Since "disgusting" is a more dramatic word than the more common "sick," it has the effect of evoking even higher praise.

Other examples you could hear anywhere from [MLG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Major_League_Gaming) commentary to highlights on [*SportsCenter*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SportsCenter):

- "disgusting play"
- "sick catch" (for example, in baseball)
- "gross moves" (for example, in skateboarding)
- "nasty headshot" (for example, in Counter Strike)

Comment: Perfect. I forgot that "sick" can be used too.